# Sepate Dashboard with preogess analytics in tutor lms

Tags: wordpress, lms

Is there any way that I can create a separate student dashboard where I can put students' progress in each course.?

The tutor LMS provides a student dashboard but not detailed analytics for course progress. Need a separate dashboard for the students